# Which one is best: Setting state using a public property or an overloaded constructor that accepts a parameter?

Tags: .net, winforms, constructor, properties

Which one should you use when you want to set the state of a Windows Forms control:

1. Setting a Windows Forms state using a public property?
2. Setting a Windows Forms state using an overloaded constructor that accepts a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They're exactly the same.** Or at least they *should* be, according to the Framework Design Guidelines. So you can expect that any of the standard classes exposed by the .NET Framework behave this way.

Any constructor method that accepts a parameter corresponding to a property should do nothing more than set that property to the specified value.

Quoting from [*Framework Design Guidelines* by Cwalina and Abrams](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756):

> **Do** use constructor parameters as shortcuts for setting main properties.
>
> There should be no difference in semantics between using the empty constructor followed by some property sets, and using a constructor with multiple arguments. The following three code samples are equivalent:

```
//1
EventLog applicationLog = new EventLog();
applicationLog.MachineName = "BillingServer";
applicationLog.Log = "Application";

//2
EventLog applicationLog = new EventLog("Application");
applicationLog.MachineName = "BillingServer";

//3
EventLog applicationLog = new EventLog("Application", "BillingServer");
```

Similar guidelines concerning constructors are also available online from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this convention:

- If the initial state **is required** by the object beeing constructed:

  - put it into the constructor.
- If it is optional or there is a meanful defaut or the object can live without it:

  - donot put into the constructor.

This way you can see what is necessary to create the object.

Comment: The Framework Design Guidelines also indicate that there should be no such property, and I can't think of an example of any class that violates that guideline, either. *All* properties are "optional" in the sense that there are acceptable defaults provided. There isn't an object that *requires* a property be set upon creation.

Answer (score 0):

IF I am creating my own class , and feel that certain properties are absolutely required for entire lifetime of an object, I will use constructor to set it for me. This way, it becomes less confusing for the ones who end up using my class.

For e,g I always prefer setting connection string in the connection string itself rather than explicitly setting property for it.

Also there is good link at MSDN on constructor design;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060(v=VS.80).aspx